# Having Trouble Printing Calculation in Textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 textboxes on my form. The 1st takes input, which is then calculated to see if its value is between the for loop and then printed in the 2nd text box. I'm having trouble printing the value after the owed is calculated. I first converted the taxable variable to double and then I'm trying to print the owed in the second box but I can't find what I'm doing wrong. Does anyone have suggestions for what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

```
private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double taxable = Convert.ToDouble(txtTaxable.Text);
    double owed = Convert.ToDouble(txtOwed.Text);


    if (taxable > 0 && taxable < 100)
    {
        //once the owed is calculated I want it to print in
        // the txtOwed.Text
          owed = taxable * .1; 
        //txtOwed.Text = owed.ToString(txtIncome.Text);

    }
}
```

Comment: Do not use double when doing _financial_ math. Use the decimal data type [decimal vs double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165761/decimal-vs-double-which-one-should-i-use-and-when)

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert `owed` to a string and assign it to `txtOwed.Text`:

```
owed = taxable * .1; 
txtOwed.Text = owed.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you were able to convert the `string` into a `double` like so:

```
double owed = Convert.ToDouble(txtOwed.Text);
```

I suggest reversing that by converting your `double` into a `string` like so:

```
string temp = Convert.ToString(owed);
```

And then setting the textbox property like so:

```
txtOwed.Text = temp;
```